# Timed Out Error when initializing Costmap2DROS

Tags: navigation, costmap-2d

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have multiple turtlebots on Gazebo simulator and try to get the positions of the obstacles.

```
tf::TransformListener listener(ros::Duration(10))
costmap_2d::Costmap2DROS costmap_ros_("my_costmap", listener);
costmap_2d::Costmap2D* costmap = costmap_ros_.getCostmap();
```

This initialization works when I do it with a single turtlebot by using turtlebot_world & amcl provided by the turtlebot_gazebo package. However, when I try it on the multiple turtlebots I launch, it doesn't work. The error I get is:

"Timed out waiting for transform from base_link to map to become available before running costmap, tf error: . canTransform returned after 0.1 timeout was 0.1."

Here are the params:

global_costmap_params.yaml

```
global_costmap:
  global_frame: map
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  static_map: true
```

local_costmap_params.yaml

```
local_costmap:
   global_frame: odom
   robot_base_frame: base_link
   publish_frequency: 2.0
   static_map: false
   rolling_window: true
   width: 6.0
   height: 6.0
   resolution: 0.05
```

Could it be because my frames are not like /map /base_link, but with the prefixes for each robot like /robot1_tf/map and /robot1_tf/base_link since I have multiple robots?

Any help will be appreciated.

My tf tree: http://docdro.id/YugFJ9C

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/267164/timed-out-error-when-initializing-costmap2dros/) by [procyon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30951/procyon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 26 on 2017-07-23

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-15**:
Can you post your tf tree?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe this is a copy-paste issue but your local_costmap_params.yaml looks odd. The one from the wiki looks like this:

```
local_costmap:
  global_frame: odom
  robot_base_frame: base_link
  update_frequency: 5.0
  publish_frequency: 2.0
  static_map: false
  rolling_window: true
  width: 6.0
  height: 6.0
  resolution: 0.05
```

There's two things to notice here: everything is indented under `local_costmap` and the lack of a leading `/`. That leading `/` will push your frames to a global namespace, which is something that you may not want. I suggest reading @Jakub's excellent answer on [how to setup a simulation of multiple robots for navigation](https://answers.ros.org/question/41433/multiple-robots-simulation-and-navigation/?answer=41434#post-id-41434).

Despite the answer being old (August of 2012) it's still mostly relevant. You will have to change some of the node names in use (Hydro?), but this is what I used to get my multi-robot simulation up and running and I'm using Indigo.

Without your tf tree this is just a guess.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [procyon](https://answers.ros.org/users/30951/procyon/) on 2017-08-16**:
Thank you for your answer! Yes, it was a copy paste issue, I've just edited it to the final version I used and added the tf tree. So, I had read about the leading / and removed it afterwards. However, I still couldn't make it work and ended up creating my own subscriber for the OccupancyGrid.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-08-16**:
Great. If that worked then you should make it an answer and mark it as correct.